# Does a new PTransform require implementing or specifying a TransformTranslator?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried writing a custom Beam source wrapped in a PTransform.

When trying to unit test locally I get the following error at runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No translator known for my.new.PTransform
at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.urnForTransform(PTransformTranslation.java:191)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.RootProviderRegistry.getInitialInputs(RootProviderRegistry.java:69)
```

I don't see any mention of TransformTranslators this in the [guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-java/) or the [PTransform Style Guide](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/ptransform-style-guide/#exposing-a-ptransform-vs-something-else).

I see several answers to this exception indicating a problem with maven shading. However I do not use or wish to build an uber/fat jar, I am fine with fetching dependencies when I build my Dataflow template.

Does anybody know what the issue might be - Would a test pipeline really need shading or something new here without mentioning it in the guide?

(And out of interest: What is an URN in this context?)

Failing that, does anybody know where the source code might be, so I can debug it (note the repackaged bit in the class path; doesn't seem to match the Beam downloadable SDK sources)?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually I think it does require a TransformTranslator.. or I can use the oven-ready method Read.of(..) to wrap my Source in a PTransform. That didn't seem very clear at all from guide, so let me try a bit more before commenting/closing.

Comment: Could you share you code ?

Comment: Could you please share complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the [guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-java/) - where it says "One or more user-facing wrapper composite transforms (PTransform) that wrap read operations", the following is sufficient:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read.from(new MyNewSource())
```